# Making third party I/O DLL asynchronous

Tags: c#, c++, async-await

I need to use a third-party DLL which implements a TCP socket client (in C++) using blocking calls. So basically (pseudocode);

```
void DoRequest()
{
  send(myblockingSocket,data); 
  recv(myblockingSocket,responsedata);
}
```

What is the recommended way to make these calls accessible in .NET as asynchronous calls using async-await **(without changing the original DLL)** ?

I read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth#deeper-dive-into-tasks-for-an-io-bound-operation and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async and several other pages and did not find another solution than spawning a new task, which is not recommended to do on I/O bound operations because of the task creation overhead.

Comment: rewrite dll, or write self from 0

Comment: either spawning threads or modify thrid party library

Comment: You could create a wrapper around the DLL you want to use, it will manage a thread-pool, and you would delegate the DLL calls to the threads to be executed asynchronously.

Comment: What is the intent? True asynchronous calls would need to use async IO when interfacing with the OS, and this would not be possible changing the dll. You could fake it by running calls on separate threads, but then you do not gain the major benefit from async IO. And then you might just as well leave the async part to the client to use when needed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "I/O bound operations", the issue is uncooperative code that blocks.  Only way to make it async is with a task, overhead is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @JonasH: The intent is to offer async calls.

Comment: @HansPassant : agree, I've been looking at it the wrong way I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the recommended way to make these calls accessible in .NET as asynchronous calls using async-await (without changing the original DLL) ?

There is no recommended solution because this isn't possible. Either the DLL itself must be changed/replaced so that it supports asynchrony, or the asynchronous calls will just be running the synchronous code on a background thread - what I call "fake asynchrony" because it *appears* asynchronous but is actually taking up a thread anyway.

> ... did not find another solution than spawning a new task, which is not recommended to do on I/O bound operations because of the task creation overhead.

It's actually [not recommended](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) for a couple of reasons:

1. It lies to the upstream code. It says "this API is asynchronous" when it's not. This can lead consumers to make incorrect decisions, e.g., preferring the asynchronous API in a server scenario.
2. It doesn't provide any actual benefit. Implementing a method with `Task.Run` forces the consumers to use an additional thread. If you just kept the API synchronous, then consumers can choose to call it with `Task.Run` or not, depending on their needs.

Comment: Thank you! Nice article in the link btw.